# I need to copy data from remote Postgres server that has limited disk space and limited connectivity to a server

Tags: postgresql, remote, copy

I have a remote Postgres server recording some data every second. the server has very less space like 6-7 GB, currently I write data to a remote VM server but due to poor connectivity the applications fails everyday without notice (I believe as I get error 0x80004005 which is a ODBC related error). I need to fix this and I thought if I can run a local server which store data and the VM server periodically connects>copies>confirms data>deletes the original data. So that even if the connectivity issues occurs the VM can try next time and when gets the data executes the procedure. I can fix this interval as hourly or daily to avoid the data loss.

I am a newbie on DB and really stuck with an app that needs some fix. (The original developer of the app is not available so I have need to get this fixed by myself). Someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't need a local server, just a queue file that you write the data to then insert in batches into the server when it's available.

Just log to a local CSV file or something.

Alternately, you could use something like Londiste (from Skytools) to replicate the rows from a local server to the remote. It's pretty fault-tolerant.

Finally, the team I'm involved in will soon be releasing [a new replication option for PostgreSQL that would meet your needs rather nicely](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide). It's a few weeks/months off production release, though.

Comment: Can you link to me a newbie tutorial in achieving this. Also your solutions will it be applicable as my connection breaks often for 5 min or so and the client has a application which rights to remote server.

Comment: Londiste wont work with writes on the remote end too. Bucardo does I think - haven't used it. If there are writes on the remote end I strongly recommend just queuing/buffering local writes and sending batches with `copy` when the server is up. No, I don't have a newbie tutorial for this. You will have to put the pieces together yourself. Look at the `copy` command and your programming lanugage's support for CSV...